# MySQL Using Obscene Amounts of Memory

Tags: mysql

Setup the MySQL server on an Ubuntu 9.10 server box, using my-small.cnf, yet it's still using over 100% of my memory (Burst).

Top reports:
[alt text http://anyhub.net/file/top.png](http://anyhub.net/file/top.png)

Comment: Which part of this top output makes you think it's using more than 100%?  I see 6.3% usage, with 15 MB actual and 109 MB virtual.

Comment: I have MoxieVM which checks the memory usage in total, which is telling me out of the 128MB I have (small box, I know), I'm using 150+MB of it.
Issue somewhere in the measurements of MoxieVM?

Comment: No idea, as I'm a "top" and "ps" user.  All this new-fangled stuff gets in the way.  :)  mysql is going to use memory.  It's a database application.  If nothing else, it will likely map the database files into memory, it will have a cache, etc.  My guess is that 128 MB is just not going ot be large enough if you're hitting the limit with a small, sample database.

Comment: No but the point is it's not even got a database, it's just the service alone...
-Edit-
MoxieVM is a service by Fivebean which monitors your servers stuff for you. It's a bit like cPanel stats.

Comment: On the contrary, it will have at least the mysql database. Won't start without it. There's also the schema virtual database, which exists only in memory.

Answer (score 1):

109MB *VIRT* is not that much. (For comparison, my database server right now  is using about 900mb VIRT + 500mb RSS)

VIRT will include things like mapped files and what not.  Your app is not using 94mb of swap (109mb(virt) - 15mb (rss)), a big chunk of that VIRT are mapped database tables,  on-disk binaries, libraries and other on-disk datafiles.

If that value is of concern to you, you can adjust it by tweaking the paramaters in my.cnf down a bit.  Remember that each idle connection uses a bit of memory, so adjusting MaxConnections to use an optimal amount of memory on your host will be a black art.

From your TOP screen I notice you don't have any swap.  Remember that linux will manage swap intellegently, and it will swap out pages that arn't being used all that much to make room for disk cache, which will help tremendously with system performance.  It's generally considered bad to have zero swap: If your disabling swap becuase your system was swapping to death before, your system's memory is woefully undersized, and no-swap will just hurt performance or hit the OOM killer sooner.

Comment: +1 RES/RSS is more useful than VIRT

Answer (score 0):

Possibly you just don't have enough memory to start with.

Not a MySQL specialist here, but I do a lot of database stuff on SQL Server. Databases CAN be memory intensive and CAN be IO intensive. Both does NOT bode well with low end virtual machines. 100mb for the process leaves not exactly a lot of memory for the database cache - if you take out the process itself, plus some caches for plans etc.

There is a chance you will jsut have to get in some more memory - depending on the database use, we may talk of gigabytes here. All that for avoiding IO. An no, that is not MySQL / SQL Server specific - databases try to cache in order to avoid IO, because IO is SLOW. Databases LIVE on RAM and IO. I know of databaes using more than 16gb of memory just to avoid caching ;)

And - sorry - a 100mb memory db process is not using obscene amounts of memory (in: large)... it may be sing obscenely low amounts of memory.

The main question is: how uch data do you have? What do oyu do with it?